# How to implement dropout in Flux.jl?

Tags: julia, flux.jl

My current model is suffering from overfitting. I want to be able to add dropout to my model such that I prevent overfitting by shutting down some neurons. I was reading through [this article on dropout](https://medium.com/@amarbudhiraja/https-medium-com-amarbudhiraja-learning-less-to-learn-better-dropout-in-deep-machine-learning-74334da4bfc5) which mentioned that you usually want dropout to take place during forward and backward passes. However, when I was reading the [Flux.jl docs section on dropout](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/layers/#Flux.Dropout), it mentions the `Dropout` layer only is part of the forward pass. Is there a way I can use this function or other similar features to have dropout in both my forward and backward passes?

Comment: If you set the neurons to be 0 in the forward pass, wouldn't their derivative be 0 on the backward pass? Thus what you're asking for is the same as what Flux is doing? They just don't bother turning them off as the maths would make the changes to be 0 anyways?

Comment: This sounds reasonable! I am not an expert in ML so not sure I know the answer but it sounds fair.